# Arcade owner (in mechanized wheelchair?) attacked and eaten by city alligator

Tags: story-identification

I have a scene, I think from a longer book, stuck in my head, hoping for some help in getting it out. The protagonists are visiting an arcade on a future Earth, I think within a recognizable city like New York. I don't remember what information they were there for, but near the end of the scene where they're talking to the owner, a giant alligator walks in and attacks the owner. As I recall it, they were considered one of the general nuisances of the city, breeding in the sewers, that you just dealt with. The arcade owner may have been in a mechanized wheelchair with weaponry. I do remember that, as the alligator attacked, one of the arcade games sprouted machine guns and tank treads and joined in the fight. I'm pretty sure that the arcade owner was eaten as the protagonists moved on in the story.

As to when I read this, that's very hazy, but I think it was before 2000, almost certainly before 2006, and probably after 1990. It was in English. Again, I'm not 100% certain whether it was a story in itself or part of a larger book, although my brain is focused on the latter. If so, I think it happened fairly early in the book.

At first, I was thinking it might have been a scene in *[Hoka! Hoka! Hoka!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoka!_Hoka!_Hoka!)* or *[Anti-Grav Unlimited](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/172339.Anti_Grav_Unlimited)*, but copies borrowed from the Internet Archive have not turned up the scene.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm quite sure the book is [Terra! by Stefano Benni](https://openlibrary.org/works/OL959605W/Terra!).

The scene about the arcade owner is at the beginning, when the main characters visit the underground levels of post-atomic war Paris.

Dekku N'Gombo is an old friend of one of the main characters, and owns some very realistic arcade games (like a version of Asteroid where, if you can't dodge an asteroid, you're crushed by a real boulder...) He is in a mechanized wheelchair with guns, and is killed by a "supercroc" and its tail swipe. The protagonists are saved by a Japanese arcade machine which sprouts a laser gun and shoots the crocodile, albeit too late to save N'Gombo.

I haven't been able to find a synopsis of the book in English, but [this](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terra!) is the Italian Wikipedia page and [this](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/2539515.Terra_) is the Goodreads page.

From Goodreads (very roughly translated by me):

> È l'anno 2156: da una Parigi sotterranea e da un mondo ghiacciato dalle guerre nucleari, parte un'incredibile corsa spaziale, verso una nuova Terra più vivibile.
>
> It's the year 2156: from an underground Paris and a world frozen by the nuclear wars, an unbelievable space race begins, toward a new, livable, Earth.

Comment: That does look familiar, and the similar exclamation point may be where I associated it with *Hoka! Hoka! Hoka!*. I'll see if I can dig up more.

Comment: Dekku N'Gombo, Page 41, indeed in a wheelchair with machine guns. Killed by a "supercroc" and its tail swipe. The arcade game did not sprout treads, but a laser gun. Thank you.
https://archive.org/details/terrabenn00benn/page/40/mode/2up